# Why is this update-with-join mysql query so slow?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join

I have an application that needs to update nodes in a hierarchical structure, upwards from a particular node whose ID is known. I use the following MySQL statement to do this:

```
update node as A 
join node as B 
   on A.lft<=B.lft and A.rgt>=B.rgt 
set A.count=A.count+1 where B.id=?
```

The table has a primary key on id, and indexes on lft and rgt. The statement works, but I found that it had performance problems. Looking at the EXPLAIN results for the corresponding select statement, I saw that the number of rows inspected for the "B" table was very large (maybe the entire table).

I can easily pull the query apart into two separate ones:

```
select lft, rgt from node where id=?
LFT=result.lft
RGT=result.rgt
update node set count=count+1 where lft<=LFT and rgt>=RGT
```

But why does the original statement not perform as expected, and how would I need to reformulate it to work better?

By request, here's an abbreviated version of the create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `node` ( 
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
`lft` decimal(64,0) NOT NULL, 
`rgt` decimal(64,0) NOT NULL, 
`count` int(11) NOT NULL default '0', 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
KEY `name` (`name`), 
KEY `location` (`location`(255)), 
KEY `lft` (`lft`), 
KEY `rgt` (`rgt`), 
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

I have not tried to add the composite index (actually, I don't have the access level required to do that on the spot); but I don't see how it would help, trying to think through how the database engine would try to resolve the dual inequalities.

Comment: It would help if you could post both the table definitions and the explain...

Comment: Can you post the `CREATE TABLE` statement and the `EXPLAIN output?

Comment: BTW: the condition `A.lft<=B.lft and A.rgt>=B.rgt ` is true for `A==B`. Is that the intended behaviour?

Comment: yes, that's intended :-)

Comment: Is the table MyISAM or InnoDB?

Answer (score 9):

You can "force" (at least up to 5.5, version 5.6 has sevral improvements on the optimizer which may make this rewriting redundant) MySQL to evaluate first the conditions on table B by taking the first part of your split into as a subquery and then using this as a derived table and joining to table A:

```
UPDATE node AS a 
  JOIN 
    ( SELECT lft, rgt
      FROM node
      WHERE id = ? 
    ) AS b 
    ON  a.lft <= b.lft 
    AND a.rgt >= b.rgt
SET 
    a.count = a.count + 1 ;
```

Efficiency will still depend on which of the two indexes is chosen to limit the rows to be updated. Still after the use of any of these 2 indexes, table lookups are needed to check the other column. So, I suggest you add a composite index on `(lft, rgt)` and one on `(rgt, lft)` so only one index is used to find which rows shall be updated.

I suppose that you are using the Nested Set and the efficiency of this update will not be great on a big table as the query has 2 range conditions and that limits the efficiency of B-tree indexes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried running this through explain, and it doesn't look promising. With apologies for the crappy formatting, the explain output is:1|PRIMARY||system|null|null|null|null|1||
1|PRIMARY|a|ALL|lft,rgt|null|null|null|999331|Using where|
2|DERIVED|node|const|PRIMARY|PRIMARY|4||1||  -- still showing a large number of rows to be inspected.

Comment: On the other hand, the simple query "select * from node where lft<=? and rgt>=?" yields the following explain: 1|SIMPLE|node|range|lft,rgt|lft|29|null|8|Using where|

Comment: Can you edit the question and update with the information asked? (CREATE TABLE statement, engine, etc.)? And did you add the composite index(es)?

Answer (score 4):

I guess your biggest performance problem is the unneeded `JOIN` you're using. You can do it by just doing two little subqueries, instead of joining two big tables.

Here is the example:

```
UPDATE node AS a
SET a.count = a.count+1 
WHERE a.lft <= (SELECT lft FROM node WHERE id = ?) 
AND  a.rgt >= (SELECT rgt FROM node WHERE id = ?)
```

Comment: That is exactly the same query as the deleted answer by @Guerra I don't like the two scalar subqueries, but mysql seems to work in mysterious ways...

Comment: Yes, it is the same from @Guerra. I don't know why he deleted the post, because the query has a better performance than the question; he should just explain that the aliases doesn't decrease performance.

Comment: He had a strange theory that the use of correlation names / aliases caused the slow query result.

Comment: But he just had to assume the error and keep the code. No big deal.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will mysql optimize this to run the two subqueries just once? Not a big deal, just wondering.

Comment: I'm quite certain that Oracle optimize that way, not sure about MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a suggestion; I don't know if it will work.

The problem with your query is that you have inequalities on two columns.  This makes it very difficult to use indexes for both of them -- which in turn makes the `join` very inefficient.  This idea is to do two joins, one for each side of the inequality, and then include the `id` in the `on` conditions.  So, only nodes that pass both will come through:

```
UPDATE node a JOIN 
      (SELECT lft, rgt
       FROM node
       WHERE id = ? 
      ) l
      ON a.lft <= l.lft  join
      (SELECT lft, rgt
       FROM node
       WHERE id = ? 
      ) r
      on a.rgt >= r.rgt
    SET a.count = a.count + 1 ;
```

As I say, I don't know if this will work.  But you should be able to readily check the `explain` for the query to see if the plan is using indexes for both inequalities.

Comment: Is the `l.id = r.id` necessary? Because you already put them equals `?`.

Comment: @LucasHarada . . . I think you are right.  The two subqueries should be getting the same row.  I'm just trying to split it into two explicit joins so both indexes can be used.

Answer (score 1):

I know that mysql has problems with referring to the table being updated, but to me the obvious solution would be:

```
update node  A 
set A.count=A.count+1
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM node B 
   WHERE B.id=?
   AND A.lft<=B.lft and A.rgt>=B.rgt
   );
```